# How to verify if clone() is called in a `move` closure?

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and I'd like to verify if `clone()` is called for a `move` closure.

I defined a type of `Test` and implemented the `Clone` trait:

```rust
struct Test {
    b : bool,
}

impl Clone for Test {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        println!("clone called");
        *self
    }
    
}

impl Copy for Test {
    
}
```

then I use it in a `move` closure:

```rust
    let test = Test{b:true};

    println!("Memory address of test: {:?}", std::ptr::addr_of!(test.b));

    let c = move || { println!("Memory address of test: {:?}", std::ptr::addr_of!(test.b)); };
    c();    // <--- does clone() be called here?

    println!("Memory address of test: {:?}", std::ptr::addr_of!(test.b));
```

I'm expecting in `c()`, `"clone called"` will be printed, but it does not.

Why? `Clone()` is not called?

the output is like:

```
> Memory address of test: 0xdf46ddfa9f 
> Memory address of test: 0xdf46ddfaef
> Memory address of test: 0xdf46ddfa9f
```

The address is changed which means `test` is copied or cloned.

In this case, how to verify when `clone()` is called?

Comment: `clone` is never implicitly called. You have to call it yourself, or call something that calls it (e.g. `Iterator::cloned`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `move` closure will *never* call `clone()`. Any clones would have to be made explicitly.

What you are seeing is that `test` is *moved* into the closure, which would normally be a problem for your last `println!`, however because your type implements `Copy`, a *copy* is made and moved into the closure instead. Whenever a `Copy` type is *moved*, it is really *copied*.

Because `Copy` is not user-defineable and used implicitly, it is usually not a good idea to add logic to its `Clone` implementation. The idiomatic way to define a `Copy` type is with derive macros: `#[derive(Copy, Clone)] struct Test { ...`.

Comment: It's not just "not a good idea", it's a violation of the `Clone` contract, and anything but UB is allowed to happen if you do it.